# Software to parse an .ics calendar file

Tags: calendar, text-processing, data, file-converter, file-format

What software can quickly and easily perform the following task:

Separate the events from a single .ics calendar file that contains multiple calendars into separate .ics files, one for each calendar.

The data is all ASCII text, and the format is:

`BEGIN:VEVENT
...data...
ORGANIZER:CN=[calendar name]
...data...
END:VEVENT`

(full format specifications can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Technical_specifications))

All I want is to create multiple .ics files, each containing only events from the respective calendar.

*Requirements:*

1. OS: Windows or Android
2. If for Windows, does not require installing a large programming environment

*Preferences:*

1. If for Windows, have a portable version, or at least a "no installer" version
2. Gratis (free of charge)

Comment: [This similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33901/642706) lists some Java libraries.

Comment: It's very easy to write the program you want (it will take less than 50 lines of code) in Python using this library: https://icspy.readthedocs.io/